# Automorphisms of a certain digraph defined on the set of primes? [Edited]

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory

Define a digraph $P=(V,E)$ with $V$ equal to the set of prime numbers and an arrow from $p$ to $q$ if $p|q-1$ (definition motivated by Pratt's primality certificates).

Does $P$ indeed admit only the trivial automorphism (as seems reasonable to guess)?

Edit:  In light of Gjergji Zaimi's heuristic suggesting a very large automorphism group, perhaps the better question asks what can one say, otherwise unconditionally, about hypothetical nontrivial automorphisms of $P$ and the permutations of ${\Bbb N}$ that they induce.

Comment: Is the solution known if p,q are not necessary prime, just naturals?

Comment: @joro  I believe Gjergji Zaimi's sketch works unconditionally with the requirement of primality dropped.

Answer (score 8):

I would expect this digraph to have a *lot* of automorphisms, but I cannot prove it unconditionally.

First, notice that $2$ is the only prime with no incoming edges. The primes which have incoming edges only from $2$ are the Fermat primes. You can keep going defining new collection of primes with incoming edges from a specific set of primes that were already considered.

Here is a conjecture: For any primes $2=p_1\le p_2 \le \cdots \le p_k$ there are infinitely many primes $q$ so that $q=1+p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$. (This seems like a reasonable conjecture generalizing the infinitude of Fermat primes.)

Assuming this conjecture, for any collection of primes previously considered there is an infinite set of primes whose incoming edges come exactly from this set of primes. This implies that in this graph, for example, the Fermat primes can not be distinguished. But there are of course many more automorphisms.

I must say, however, that for all I know, there are only finitely many Fermat primes, or even better, for every set of primes $S$ there are only finitely many primes so that $q-1$ has $S$ as its set of prime factors. If, moreover, the number of such primes is distinct for ever $S$, then the graph turns out to be rigid (no automorphisms). But deciding unconditionally which is the case should be very hard.

Comment: If one views the potential Fermat primes merely as typical numbers of there size, the prime number theorem would lead you to guess only finitely many. 

Comment: @David The same heuristic does suggest infinitely many primes of the form $2^m 3^n + 1$, though.  These are called Pierpont primes.

Comment: So if I understand, you expect the automorphism group to look like a countably-iterated wreath product, right?  

Comment: And you expect two primes in the same orbit if their "Pratt trees" have the same topology, right? 

Comment: You don't mention the infinitely many outgoing edges. Can you prove it for p,q in N?

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem does guarantee infinitely many primes q of the form pk+1.  Must think about your question.  BTW, scare quotes, because "Pratt trees" are not generally trees, but rather quotients of trees.


Comment: @David, one can obviously distinguish between primes which have non-isomorphic Pratt trees, but on the other hand, given the "infinite outdegrees" hypothesis, the Pratt tree (or Pratt DAG more precisely :)) is the only distinguishing factor, so your comment above seems absolutely right.

Comment: It would be interesting to know (asymptotically, as a function of $x$) the number of distinct Pratt DAGs that occur for primes less than $x$.  

Comment: Another thought: given $n$, then for $0<i<n$ one could give color $c_i$ to edges such that $p^i|q-1$ but not $p^{i+1}|q-1$ with color $c_n$ for all other edges.  Doesn't the same logic still suggest an uncountable automorphism group?  Then these automorphism groups would give a filtration by subgroups as $n$ increases.  Not sure where to go from there, but this filtered groups would seem to encode a great deal of arithmetic.